# Why does this class program not return the balance?

Tags: python, class, account

Question:  Develop a class `BankAccount` that supports these methods:
`__init__()`: Initializes the bank account balance to the value of the input argument or to 0 if no input argument is given

`withdraw()`: Take an argument as an input and withdraws it from the balance

`deposit()`: Take an amount as an input and add it to the balance

`balance()`: Returns the balance on the account

```
class ValueErrorException (Exception):
    pass

class BankAccount:

    accounts = 0

    def __init__ (self, bal = 0.0):
        BankAccount.accounts += 1
        self.accountNumber = str(BankAccount.accounts)
        self.balance = bal


    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if self.balance - amount < 0:
            raise ValueErrorException("Illegal balance")
        else:
            self.balance -= amount


    def deposit (self, amount):
        self.balance += amount


    def balance(self, amount):
        return amount
```

Comment: use self. you seem to be using it everywhere but the return amount

Comment: so why is there `return amount` in `def balance` if `balance` is supposed to return the balance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The balance definition should be like this:

```
def balance(self):
    return self.balance
```

You may also want to consider changing the variable name from `balance` to `accountBalance` so it doesn't affect the definition that is named the same.  Your new code would now be:

```
class ValueErrorException (Exception):

    pass

class BankAccount:

    accounts = 0

    def __init__ (self, bal = 0.0):
        BankAccount.accounts += 1
        self.accountNumber = str(BankAccount.accounts)
        self.accountBalance = bal


    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if self.accountBalance - amount < 0:
            raise ValueErrorException("Illegal balance")
        else:
            self.accountBalance -= amount


    def deposit (self, amount):
        self.accountBalance += amount


    def balance(self):
        return self.accountBalance
```

Answer (score 0):

`return self.balance`

access the classes instance variable, not a functional argument. no need to pass amount to a function just to return it